# Reorder constructor parameters

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, parameters, constructor

Is given a class that takes a bunch of parameters in the explicit constructor.
What i have to do is to reorder this parameters. That is going to chain into a lot of change in unit testing and whatever place I use that class.
Is there any way, tool or something, that can switch parameters between them in the whole solution where that class is used?

**Example:**

*Change*

```
public ClassName(string first,string second, string 3rd)
{
}
```

*Into*

```
Public ClassName(string second, string 3rd, string first)
{
}
```

Comment: Reordering parameters is [built into Visual Studio refactoring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/csharp-ide/refactoring/change-method-signature)

Comment: Also worth mentioning is that, since C# 4, you always have the option of using named parameters. This is especially useful when you have multiple parameters with the same type that give no obvious indication of what they mean when encountered in code (`ClassName(true, false, true)` versus `ClassName(useWidgets: true, terminateUserOnError: false, avoidTaxes: true)`. In this case, the order of the parameters in the declaration is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with built-in [Change Signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/csharp-ide/refactoring/change-method-signature) refactoring (not sure exactly in which versions of VS that is available). If it's not available in your VS version, there is also [Reorder Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ss5z206.aspx) refactoring which is available since VS 2008.